# SGD to maximize distances

Tags: python, optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to solve an optimization problem that is to find a farthest point from a list of points. Say, within a valid region, find an optimal `x` so that distance `D(x, c1) + D(x, c2) + ... D(x, cn)` is the maximum. 
I was hinted to solve it by stochastic gradient descent so I have completed the distance function as below:

```
def distance(loc_x, loc_c):
  """
  arg:
    loc_x: 1x2 array: decision variable
    loc_c: 662x2 array: locations x needs to be away as much as possible
  """
  return np.sum(np.power(np.sum(np.power(loc_x - loc_c, 2), axis=1), 1/2))
```

But I don't know how to proceed programmatically. Mathematically I know I want to calculate the derivative for distance and get `x_opt` when the `derivative = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the derivative of the negative distance function(loss function) which you try to minimize and the start with some random x and keep finding next x using incremental steps with some gamma learning rate.

```
def df(x):
    # derivative function of your distance function
    return 
max_iters = 100
for _i in range(max_iters):
    current_x = next_x
    next_x = current_x - gamma * df(current_x)
    step = next_x - current_x
print(current_x)
```